# Read key value from JSON node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have similar to next json:

```
{
    'igor': {'password': '12345678', 'color': 'white'),
    'ruslan': {'password': '87654321', 'color': 'black')
}
```

And also have variable

```
var name = 'igor';
```

How can I get password value, using this variable to detect name? I tried next:

```
obj[name['password']]
```

But it returns undefined; also tried:

```
obj.name['password']
```

As well it returns undefined. How should I get that value? Thanks.

Comment: `obj[name]['password']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nano commented, to access "password" for the object with the key "igor" you need to use `obj[name]['password']`. This is because you have two objects one with "igor" as the key, and one as "ruslan" as the key. You could also use

```
var igor = obj['igor'];
var igorsPassword = igor['password'];
```

In addition unixarmy's form is not wrong, and the following is correct.

```
var igor = obj.igor;
var igorsPassword = igor.password;
```

That being said however, if the property name has spaces in it it must be accessed using the `obj['property name']` form, it cannot be done with `obj.property name` since the space between `property` and `name` serves as a syntax separator when not in a string/regular expression.

Comment: i cannot know before is it igor or nor, i have server-side and client-side, when user enters his name and password, it goes to server-side, and from there i take variable with name, so I can't do: var igor = obj.igor

Comment: @IgorBarakaiev Ok, I was not aware of the circumstances. That being said, the `obj[property]` form is still very much valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON example is not valid!

Anyway, you can use the following syntax: `obj[name].property`.